# Show index and not default

Tags: server, apache2

I have apache2 well working, and get the default page "it works" so that is fine.
I have, to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, added:

```
<Directory /home/meteor/webcam/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I am calling

```
192.168.1.81/home/meteor/webcam
```

I expected to get an index over directory, but I get an error 404

What have I missed in setting up this system?

The plan is to get an index as this one:  http://www.stjerneskud.info/~hobro/
Is there anywhere else inside or outside the `apache2.conf` I should change something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Apache to map some URL to this directory, for example using an [Alias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias). For example

```
Alias "/webcam" "/home/meteor/webcam"
```

lets you use `http://192.168.1.81/webcam/` to access `/home/meteor/webcam/`.

Note that on Debian based distros like Ubuntu it's better not to use `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for this type of configuration but a config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. See `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` for more about this.